# Sequence of actions clean code

Tags: scala, coding-style

I have an actor based application (using [akka](/questions/tagged/akka)) written in scala. Now I have an actor that should configure a device in the network by sending it various HTTP-requests in a predefined order.

I encapsulated all the HTTP stuff in a seperate class for my actors to access.
Each of the configuration steps can of course fail so I used `Try[Int]` as a return type of the methods that handle the communication with the device (returning the HTTP-responsecode as content of the `Try`).

Now my problem is that every configuration step depends on all steps before to have completed successfully and my code therefore becomes difficult to read (in my oppinion).

I have it implemented basically like this

```
action1 match {
  case Failure(err) => //report error
  case Success(retCode) if retCode < 400 =>
    nextStep match {
      ...
    }
}
```

After a few actions this just becomes a massive statement where you cannont see at first glance what is going on.

**So how would I go about writing this in a clean-code-ish fashion?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement your sequence of actions as ... sequence of actions:

Blocking version:

```
def seq: Seq[() => Try[Int]] = ???

// find first failure
def failed: Option[Try[Int]] = seq.view.map{ _() }.find {
    case Failure(err) =>
      //report error
      true
    case Success(retCode) => retCode > 400
  }
```

For nonblocking version you should use `Future` instead of `Try`:

```
val seq: List[() => Future[Int]] = ???

def isSuccess(actions: List[() => Future[Int]]): Future[Boolean] = actions match {
  case h :: tail => h().flatMap { c =>
      if (c > 400) Future(false)
      else isSuccess(tail)
    }
  case Nil => Future(true)
}
```

Comment: Ahh right `find` stops executing if it got a `true`. Well with hindsight this was kinda an obvious solution^^

Comment: Doesn't really matter if it blocks here as the whole purpose of this actor is to execute these actions and they have to wait on one another anyway

Comment: @mgttlinger: I don't know how you are getting `HTTP` responses, but if library provides `Future[Response]` you should not convert it to `Try` using `Await`.

Comment: I am using [scalaj-http](https://github.com/scalaj/scalaj-http) and as far as I see it does not provide the responscode as `Future`

Comment: @mgttlinger: there was a error in blocking solution. See updated version.